# Redirect Pending Review Status Preview page url to custom url

Tags: redirect

Since I am facing a issue with your wordpress that if my authors publish a page in my website then it goes to Pending Review Status. This is working fine. But the preview url of each post that is in pending review status is visible to everyone except other users also. Let me give you an example. If I am the author of your website and created a post and send to pending review after that i copied the preview url and send it to globally since everyone can see that post without getting approval of the administrator. So, I have a question, can I redirect all preview urls to any custom url or on my homepage.

Example:-
https://example.com/?p=16311&preview=true/   or     https://example.com/?p=16311
TO
https://example.com/under-approval/

This is very serious issue which each of your users will face in future. For reference I also added a link of that page such that you can also check that the pending review post is visible to everyone…

For reference you can check this url
https://thefaceofindia.in/?p=16309&preview=true

This url is opening worldwide without getting approval of administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function mmk_pending_review_redirect(){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if(get_post_status ( get_the_id() ) != 'publish')
            if (is_user_logged_in() && !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) && !is_author() ) {
                wp_redirect( "https://example.com/under-approval");
                exit;
            }else{
              wp_redirect( "https://example.com/under-approval") );
              exit;
            }
        }
    }
add_action('template_redirect', 'mmk_pending_review_redirect');
```

explanation: redirect non-admin users to custom URL if they are not author of the current post where status is not published. (change page id to your custom page)

Comment: I want to show pending review post only to administrator not to author and anybody else, i want to redirect the specific page if to any custom url if anybody tries to visit that pending review page. https://example.com/?p=16374&preview=true to any custom page

Comment: i have updated the code so if a user is not logged in and tries to access a post that is not published it will be redirected. if a user is logged in but not with admin role it will also get redirected. you can modify/remove this part get_permalink( $custom_url_id ) to give your own custom url.

Comment: I have updated the code , check

Comment: but this code is redirecting all my 404 pages, I only want to redirect pending review pages.

Comment: remove this part, else{
              wp_redirect( "https://example.com/under-approval") );
              exit;
            } non logged in users won't be able to see the page anyways, and get 404 if they try to access it.

Comment: Hey, I implemented this code on my second website If a user is not logged in and tries to visit any of my category links it is opening and even if he tries to open a pending review post then it is redirecting to under approval page. This is working perfect as I wanted. But if that user logged in to my website as a Role (snax-author) , or any other role then this redirects all my category page links to that page i.e (/under-approval), eg - if a logged in user visits my category page that is located in my menu, then its redirecting to under-approval page.

Comment: replace first condition with this one  if(get_post_status ( get_the_id() ) != 'publish'  && is_singular( 'post' ) )       //it works only for blog type posts if you want to enable it for every post then remove post from is_singular